# @ sign has no effect in C# aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using Webmatrix to write my aspx and I find that @ has no effect to my asp codes.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<html>
<body>
@for(var i = 10; i < 21; i++)
{<p>Line @i</p>}
</body>
</html>
```

This program, instead of outputing Line 1, Line 2, etc..., it outputs

> @for(var i = 10; i < 21; i++) {
>
> Line @i
>
> }

Can anyone please help me to solve this? All I have in my workspace is the Default.aspx. Am I missing some config files?

Comment: Are you using WebForms of MVC? Which version?

Comment: are you using a *.cshtml file?

Answer (score 7):

I'm guessing you don't have your application set up to use the Razor View Engine. You either need to switch to the new view engine, or write your application using the old WebForms View Engine syntax:

```
<% for(var i = 10; i < 21; i++) { %>
    <p>Line <%= i %></p>
<% } %>
```